# each entry of a list nummered bij order

Tags: python, list

I am trying to nummer all my entry's in a list by order my script is :

```
   for item in klantgegevens:
       teller = (number, item)
       number = number + 1
       print teller
```

klantgegevens :

```
(['Cautus B.V. Zei 9-11', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', ' Zei 9-11', '1009023', '10', 'Geachte Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2000@planet.nl']) 
(['Cautus B.V. 32', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', 'Trias 92', '1109008', '10', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2100@planet.nl'])
```

And i want my output to be :

```
    (0, ['Cautus B.V. Zei 9-11', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', ' Zei 9-11', '1009023', '10', 'Geachte Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2000@planet.nl']) 
    (1, ['Cautus B.V. 32', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', 'Trias 92', '1109008', '10', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2100@planet.nl'])
     2 .....
     3 .....
     4 ....
```

Comment: Your `klantgegevens` is no proper datatype. It's 2 tuples side by side.

Comment: so `klantgegevens` is a list of lists? because you posted the items as separate tuples.

Comment: i only used 2 entry's as an example this is how it get's printed out but it is a list of lists

Comment: So if you print your `klantgegevens` with the code `for elem in klantgegevens: print elem` you get the result that you show in your question as `klantgegevens`?

Comment: no i got another klantgegevens with all the elements but i appended that 1 to this 1 so it's only 1 element.This so i can nummer all the entry's otherwise it loops overt all the elements

Comment: Then change the `enumerate(klantgegevens)` to `enumerate(klantgegevens[0])`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the builtin [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function. It seems that you have a list with one element that is a list of lists so you have to call `enumerate` on this one element (the list of lists):

```
for teller in enumerate(klantgegevens[0]):
    print teller
```

Answer (score 0):

use `enumerate()` here:

```
In [229]: klantgegevens=[['Cautus B.V. Zei 9-11', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', ' Zei 9-11', '1009023', '10', 'Geachte Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2000@planet.nl'],
['Cautus B.V. 32', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', 'Trias 92', '1109008', '10', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2100@planet.nl']]

In [231]: for i,x in enumerate(klantgegevens):
   .....:     print (i,x)
   .....:     
   .....:     
(0, ['Cautus B.V. Zei 9-11', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', ' Zei 9-11', '1009023', '10', 'Geachte Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2000@planet.nl'])
(1, ['Cautus B.V. 32', 'Cautus B.V.', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', 'Trias 92', '1109008', '10', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw Daa', 'chaa.c2100@planet.nl'])
```

Comment: @user1752643 how does `klantgegevens` looks like?

Comment: but i need to number every entry not every item my bad

Comment: pleasee post value of `klantgegevens` and the expected output in the question body, it's not very clear here.

Comment: i posted my input and output in the qeustion

Comment: @user1752643 Solution edited, and used `klantgegevens` as a list of lists.