# Giving a number to a entry

Tags: python, text-processing

The csv file has the following content:

```
Cautus Drogisterijen B.V.
Cautus Drogisterijen B.V.
Clever Franke
De Inrichting
Teva Pharmaceuticals Europe B.V.
```

The names get imported from a csv and then converted etc.

I have the following script:

```
#Gegevens
l = (gegevens)
#script
#Welke sleutels moet hij pakken
sortkey = operator.itemgetter(1,5)
#De identieke sleutel selecteren
l_clean = sorted(l,key=sortkey)
#delijst maken
l_final = [(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(l_clean, key = operator.itemgetter(1))]
#importeer csv optie
import csv
#bestand kiezen
with open('export.csv', 'wb') as f:
    #Write 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    #loop over de lijst
    for k,v in l_final:
    #welke gegevens hij moet tonen
       info_rest = v[0][:5]+v[0][5:]
       #combineerd de verzekeringen
       info_combine = map(operator.itemgetter(5),v)
       uniekid = k
       verzl = info_combine
       name = info_rest[0]
       risicoadr = info_rest[2]
       polisnummer = info_rest[3]
       relatienummer = info_rest[4]
       aanhef = info_rest[6]
       contactpersoon = info_rest[7]
       emailadr = info_rest[8]
       klantgegevens = []      
       #lijst met alle gegevens
       klantgegevens1 = [uniekid,naam,verz,risicoadr,polisnummer,relatienummer,aanhef,contactpersoon,emailadr]       
       klantgegevens.append (klantgegevens1)     
       for i, w in enumerate(name):
           print (i,w)

       #welke gegevens hij erin moet schrijven
       writer.writerow(klantgegevens)
```

That produces this output:

```
(0, 'C')
(1, 'a')
(2, 'u')
(3, 't')
(4, 'u')
(5, 's')
(6, ' ')
(7, 'D')
(8, 'r')
(9, 'o')
(10, 'g')
(11, 'i')
(12, 's')
(13, 't')
(14, 'e')
(15, 'r')
(16, 'i')
(17, 'j')
(18, 'e')
(19, 'n')
(20, ' ')
(21, 'B')
(22, '.')
(23, 'V')
(24, '.')
(0, 'C')
(1, 'a')
(2, 'u')
(3, 't')
(4, 'u')
(5, 's')
(6, ' ')
(7, 'D')
(8, 'r')
(9, 'o')
(10, 'g')
...
```

As you can see he loops on every letter in the name and gives the letter a number but what I want is that my output looks like this:

```
(0, 'cautus drogisterij B.V.')
(1, 'cautus drogisterij B.V.')
```

That every name gets a number.

Comment: replace print(x,i) by print(x,name) ? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: how about your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031721/each-entry-of-a-list-nummered-bij-order)?

Comment: name is a list of names and my problem is that he now loops over the word downwards but i want it to loop over the word

Comment: It would be better if you post that list of names. Because if your name is a list of names, then that would work fine.

Comment: @sjeggiepop based on the output you have shown, `name` is not a list of names, it is a str, or possibly a list of str that are all 1 character long.

Comment: it would be better if you post actual code and actual output. You have `print(x,i)` when they output is from something more similar to `print(i, x)`

Comment: That can't be your actual code -- In addition to the other comments, there is no mechanism to restart `enumerate`, so what you have must be enclosed in a loop somewhere ...

Comment: that options didn't work and tryed and searched all day for other options still can't find the solution

Comment: Try printing the `name` before your loop, whether its actually a list or not.

Comment: what does your original csv look like, and what are you trying to accomplish? at the moment it all doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @sjeggiepop. Your `info_rest` is actually a 1-D list. So your name will be a String.

Comment: @sjeggiepop: removing code like this is not conducive to a discussion and is not fair to other users, who both are going to read your question and have answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an outer loop that iterates over the list of names. Therefore this current loop iterates over string `name`. Unfortunately, supplied code is too short to glimpse anything more than that.

**Edit**: Come on your comment is clearly saying "loop over de lijst". Just remove this whole `for`-loop and just `print(k, name)`

Comment: This is to mutate the data i import from another list so i can't simply remove it

Comment: @sjeggiepop: I mean this `for`: `for i, w in enumerate(name):`

Comment: so u are saying that i make a loop in a loop and that is what creates the problem?

Comment: @sjeggiepop: `for k,v in l_final:` is an outer loop, your `for i, w in enumerate(name):` is an inner loop. Your outer loop is clearly commented with _loop over de lijst_. Yes that created a problem. I honestly don't understand what you don't understand.

Comment: well i am very new to python and just started working with it i only followed a short python tutorial and i didn't knew this sorry but there is still much to learn and this is apperently 1 of them

Answer (score 3):

If your `name` is a `list of names`, then your code should work fine, provided, you don't have another loop enclosing that loop: -

**This works**: -

```
>>> name = ['rohit', 'jain']
>>> for i,x in enumerate(name):
    print (i, x)


(0, 'rohit')
(1, 'jain')
```

**However, this is what you get**, where you might have an outer loop, iterating over the list: -

```
>>> name = ['rohit', 'jain']
>>> for name in name:
        for i, x in enumerate(name):
            print (i, x)


(0, 'r')
(1, 'o')
(2, 'h')
(3, 'i')
(4, 't')
(0, 'j')
(1, 'a')
(2, 'i')
(3, 'n')
```

---

**UPDATE**: -

Your `info_rest` is actually a 1-D list: -

```
for k,v in l_final:
    info_rest = v[0][:5]+v[0][5:]
```

The above code gives you 1-D list from the 2-D list `v`: -

```
>>> v = [['rohit', 'jain'], ['a', 'ab']]
>>> info_rest = v[0][:5]+v[0][5:]
>>> info_rest
['rohit', 'jain']
```

So, when you say: -

```
name = info_rest[0];  # name contains 'rohit;
```

Your name will contains a string rather than a list. - `'rohit'` in this case

So, rather than iterating over your name: -

```
for i, w in enumerate(name):
           print (i,w)
```

just print it: -

```
print (k, name)  # k is the index from outer loop
```

Comment: Take a look at the updated post, to the know what actual problem is

Comment: This for is to mutate data i can't simply remove it to make this work because the script will be worthless then k is btw the unique index and contains the name + street name

Comment: @sjeggiepop. Then in that case, you will get the output you are getting, because your loop is iterating over a string, not the list. Or, you need to refactor your code, and clean it up, to post only relevant code block.

Comment: @sjeggiepop. And I'm just saying to replace that for-loop with that print statement.